# reply comment below the comment box without reload page

Tags: comments, comment-form, comments-template

I make a comment form before comment list and I want to show a comment form inside the comment box that chose to reply without refresh the page

the website I inspired the idea [Novin.com](https://www.novin.com/blog/google-ads-costs/)

[image]

Comment: I guess you want to submit the comment to [the REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/comments/#create-a-comment) and update the page using JavaScript.

Comment: yes like the the [novin.com](https://www.novin.com/blog/google-ads-costs/) website 
do u know how to make that? @Rup